# How to Calculate fundamental frequency of microphone input using Harmonics data

Tags: audio, unity-game-engine, signal-processing, fft, pitch-detection

I am able to calculate the fundamental frequency of a real-time audio input from the microphone in Unity by finding the highest peak bin using GetSpectrumData function.
But it fails for lower frequencies. 
I think that I get the frequency of harmonics if I play lower frequency notes.
How can I calculate the fundamental frequency using harmonics data.

Comment: You could use a proper pitch detection algorithm instead of trying to re-invent the wheel, or if you just want something "quick and dirty"' then you could measure the distance between successive harmonics, since this will typically be the same as the fundamental frequency.

Comment: If the input is monophonic and not terribly noisy, you could just use [autocorrelation](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/386/autocorrelation-in-audio-analysis).

Comment: @Linuxios I have tried the autocorrelation, it works fine, (https://pitchtracker.codeplex.com/). But I also want the amplitude of first 7 harmonics. Is that possible using autocorrelation. If yes can you guide me in the right path.

Comment: @TUSHARKHAVALE: In that case, no, you'll need look at the spectral data.

Comment: Is it possible you are not using a long enough sample?   Lower frequencies will require a longer time-peroid (and thus more samples) to oscillate through the entire wavelength.  Only by sampling the entire wavelength can you determine the tone's peaks.  Wavelength = 1/frequency

Comment: Wavelength is not 1/fft_frequency for pitched sounds with a weak or missing fundamental.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Harmonic Product Spectrum algorithm for overtone rich monophonic pitch detection and estimation.

Cepstrums or Cepstral analysis is another possibility.

Comment: How can I use HPS algorithm?

Comment: That's a separate question.  Why not ask it?  (instead of commenting).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42694778/how-can-i-use-harmonic-product-spectrum-algorithm-for-overtone-rich-monophonic-p